# Auto-property vs. protected variable with public accessors

Tags: c#, properties

In some code that I've recently inherited the responsibility for, I've found several instances where the original developer did something like the following:

```
protected MyEnumerationType _foo;

public MyEnumerationType Foo
{
    get { return _foo; }
    set { this._foo = (MyEnumerationType) value; }
}
```

This seems unnecessarily verbose to me and I'm curious as to whether there is some advantage to doing this instead of simply using an auto-property:

```
public MyEnumerationType Foo { get; set; }
```

Am I missing something?  Is there some advantage to the first section of code above that I'm not aware of?

Comment: That cast... is like `(int)5`. Completely senseless, since value is by definition of that type. Scrap that, and the actual question appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likelihood is that the original code was written before C# 3.0 was released, which is when [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) were introduced. In earlier versions of the language, the first approach is the only one that was possible.

In C# 3.0 and later, the main advantage to explicitly defining the backing field is to perform operations on it that are not possible through properties, such as initializing it with a default value (which would otherwise have to be done through a constructor) and declaring it as volatile.

Answer (score 1):

This *can* be advantage, don't know if it's in your domain so, if you think that the class that derives from that class can access the field `MyEnumerationType _foo`, avoiding in this way (for some reason) access it via property.

It's hard to say if in your specific context there is some meaning, but, I repeat, there could be meaning described above.

For example, if I would have :

```
public MyEnumerationType Foo
{
    get { return _foo; }
    set { 
           this._foo = (MyEnumerationType) value; 
           TriggerSomething(..);
       }
}
```

so setting that property I would trigger some actions in my environment, accessing the *field* directly will help me avoid unnecessary (for architectual decisions) triggering, if I change that field from some child class.